# Make threads call init once every cycle

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a code that looks like the following, with many threads doing this code snippet:

```
if (!shouldWork)
{
    long timeToSleep = 0;

    if (FindTimeToSleep(timeToSleep)) {
        Sleep(timeToSleep);
        InnerInitialize();
    }
}
}
```

Now, The function InnerInitialize should be called only once after the sleep timeout. There are many threads that can sleep, after they wake up, only one thread should call InnerInitialize. We could use a simple semaphore, but the problem is that in the next cycle, after all the threads have passed the call to InnerInitialize, if the threads get to sleep again, we may need to call the function again (only once). So this is similar to std::call_once, but only periodically.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: the sleep process is synchronous? Is there some type of barrier? What happens if a thread on "round 5" gets up before the chosen one for the "round 4"? Or is it critical that the "first thread" being waken is the chosen one?

Comment: All the threads sleep (almost) the same amount of time, and they sleep for many minutes. So yes the sleep is synchronous.

Comment: Basically what I want is for my threads to work for a few hours, say from 15:00 to 17:00, then at 17:00 go to sleep till 15:00, and then wake up call the initialize function again, till the next round.

Comment: is there a barrier mechanism? What is the expected behaviour on a thread that arrives to the InnerInitialize? Wait for someone to execute it? Wait if someone is executing it? Execute it if nobody has started executing it?

Comment: Right now there is no barrier. When the first thread arrives on the InnerInitialize, he should call it, and all other threads have to wait till the first thread finishes the initialization. Then they should continue as normal.

Comment: Then it is ok to have a "chosen one" thread (always the same one) and a barrier? This ensures that all the threads will start synchronously and with the proper initialization. However, having (so many?) threads sleeping for so many hours seems a waste, I would recommend doing proper clean up and initialization.

Comment: I guess having a chosen thread can work. How can I implement this?

Comment: on a side note, your parenthesis don't add up - you might want to edit the code as it's hard to follow what you are doing.

Comment: I edited your post just to point out the deal with the parenthesis - I'm not sure where they should open/close I just changed the indentation.

Comment: Is `shouldWork` thread-specific or a (presumably atomic) global for all worker threads?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a shared mutex for synchronization.

ignoring how each thread gets to the `Sleep(timeToSleep)` method this is what should happen:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int initialized;
.......
Sleep(timeToSleep);

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  //critical section
if (!initialized)
{
   intialized = 1;
   InnerInitialize();
}
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
```

You still have to reset the `intialized` variable somewhere in the code but I don't fully understand it to help you with that.

This of course assumes that all threads go to sleep for the same amount of time and that period is long enough to guarantee that no thread goes to sleep(again) before all the others have woken up.

Comment: This is a too simple solution that won't work in this case, because after I unlock the mutex, I have to set  initialized = 0 (for the next cycle) , but maybe one thread didn't wake up yet after I already called innerinitialize, and he sees that initialized =0 and tries to execute the critical section again.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, I did not reset the variable because I don't fully understand how your could should work. I left that part to you. You need to make sure that the last thread going to sleep resets the variable. And you can easily do that by cheeping a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a single thread which manages the rest. Your, what seems to be per thread group, initialization and sleep between sessions would be managed from that one thread whilst the worker threads in the group would do their stuff when needed, possibly via a job queue.

This also cleanly separates out the responsibilities of each threads job.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize each thread around a "generational counter," which is simply an incrementing counter that signal its changes (via mutex and condition variable).

When the counter increments, it is a "new workday," if you will, and the workers know to begin again.  A separate, dedicated scheduling thread performs the increment and initialization routines, and it does not need to know how many workers there are.

In pseudocode:

```
// main / global init
workCycle = new GenerationalCounter()   // initialized to _generation 0

// worker thread
myCurrentCycle = 0
while true:
  myCurrentCycle = workCycle.awaitNewGeneration(myCurrentCycle)
                            // lock mutex
                            // cond_wait until _generation != myCurrentCycle
                            // fetch _generation for return
                            // unlock mutex
  DoWork()

// scheduler thread
while true:
  SleepUntilNextWorkCycle()
  InnerIntializer()
  workCycle.increment()     // lock mutex
                            // increment _generation
                            // broadcast
                            // unlock mutex
```

With a little bookkeeping, `InnerInitialize()` could be moved out of the scheduling thread and into one of the workers by extending `GenerationalCounter` to run a callback in the very first thread released after a generation increment.